# Janela para salvar Arquivo Swift

Tags: swift, osx, storyboard

Gostaria de criar uma janela para salvar arquivos de texto no disco, mas não sei como criar um File Explorer Utilizando Storyboard.

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo para `iOS` ou `OS X`?

Comment: Estou utilizando OS X

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi esse problema com o seguinte código:

```
var painelSalvar: NSSavePanel = NSSavePanel();

    painelSalvar.prompt = "Salvar";
    painelSalvar.worksWhenModal = true;
    painelSalvar.title = "Salvar Programa";
    painelSalvar.message = "";
    painelSalvar.runModal();
    var arquivo = painelSalvar.URL;
    if (arquivo != nil){
        let newString : String? = arquivo?.absoluteString!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);
        return newString!;
    }

    return "";
```